# Show Fragment when PreferenceHeader tapped?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I must be missing something. Is there any way to simply push on a new Fragment (simply a standard Android Fragment) when a `header` is tapped inside a `PreferenceActivity`?

For example, I want to show a custom number picker view I've created as a `Fragment` when the user taps on:

```
<header
android:id="@+id/preferences_date_time"
android:fragment="com.xxx.appname.view.settings.DateTimeFragment"
android:icon="@drawable/menu_icon_date"
android:title="@string/pref_date_time" >
</header>
```

This way I can show this fragment in other parts of the app (as a `Dialog`, inside an `Activity`, etc.).

The fragment is defined simply:

```
public class DateTimeFragment extends Fragment
{

    public DateTimeFragment()
    {}

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_date_time, container);

        return view;
    }
}
```

Note that the key here to my question is that I simply want to show a plain old Fragment when the header is tapped, not any of the preference fragment types.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I could find there is no way to show an arbitrary `Fragment` when tapping on a `PreferenceHeader`.

What I did instead was launch an activity that hosted the fragment I wanted to display:

```
<header
    android:id="@+id/preferences_date_time"
    android:icon="@drawable/menu_icon_date"
    android:title="@string/pref_date_time" >
    <intent
        android:action="android.intent.action.MAIN"
        android:targetClass="com.xxx.appname.view.settings.DateTimeActivity"
        android:targetPackage="com.xxx.appname" />
</header>
```

Make sure your `Activity` is listed in your `AndroidManifest.xml` or it won't be found:

```
<activity
    android:name="com.xxx.appname.view.settings.DateTimeActivity"
    android:label="@string/date_time_picker_title"
    android:parentActivityName="com.xxx.appname.view.settings.SettingsActivity"
    android:theme="@style/PreferencesTheme" >
</activity>
```

This way I can use my `Fragment` in my settings menu and anywhere else needed in the app.